# How to route an API app to be like url/something?type=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I'm working on a Rails 5.2 API and I'm a bit confused about how to do a correct routing.

When I call my API I'm writing: 
`localhost:3001/?type=arrival`

what I would like to write:
`localhost:3001/flights?type=arrival`

But I don't know what I should change and also if this can be correct as good practice doing an API.

Or should be something like: `URL/api/v1/flights?type=...`

I'm not sure what will be the best thing to do and how to change.

My `routes.rb`:

```
root to: "api/v1/flights#index"
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: '/api' do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :flights, only: [:index, :destroy_all]
  end
end
```

Comment: Just remove the first line with `root` and you get `.../api/v1/flights?type=...`. It is always a good idea to use namespace with api version - when you change version you can leave the old one working for somebody, who needs it

Answer (score 0):

When setting up an API you rarely want to have both a subdomain constraint and `/api` in the path:

```
http://api.example.com/api/v1/flights
```

Seems kind of silly. I mean what else do you have on the api subdomain?

So either go with a path:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :flights, only: [:index]
  end
end
```

Or a subdomain:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: nil do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :flights, only: [:index]
  end
end
```

To add additional REST verbs to the collection (like :destroy_all) you pass a block to `resources`:

```
resources :flights, only: [:index] do
  delete '/', action: :destroy_all, on: :collection
end
```

Comment: The root on an api server is usually some sort of static page with basic usage information or something of the sort. Putting an API endpoint on the root path does not really seem like a good idea.

Comment: I tried this way with subdomain but getting route error

Comment: This No route matches [GET] "/api/v1/flights"

Comment: You missed the whole point of the subdomain example. It mounts the route at `/v1/flights`. So you would get `http://api.example.subdomain.com/v1/flights`.

Comment: If you really want to have `http://api.example.com/api/v1/flights` remove the `path: nil` option.